# sqlite does not read .sqliterc in Cygwin

Tags: sqlite, cygwin

Does any one use sqlite with Cygwin? I setup some options in the .sqliterc under my HOME directory, as following.

```
.mode column
.header on
.nullvalue NULL
```

But when I run queries in sqlite3, it seems it does not pick up the options in my .sqliterc file. This option works fine in my Mac machine.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: It works for me, at least with a very simple test.  With no `~/.sqliterc` file, typing `sqlite3` at the bash prompt gives me the usual header and `sqlite> ` prompt.  When I run `echo .help > ~/.sqliterc ; sqlite3`, it gives me the help message followed by the header and prompt.  What does that do for you?  `sqlite3 --version` says `3.7.3`.

Answer (score 1):

please check your Home Directory.

You can find by :

```
echo $HOME
```

If your .sqliterc is located in your $HOME, and sqlite3 does not load that file,
check :

```
whoami
```

If your login name is not same to "whoami" result, please put your .sqliterc to home directory of "whoami".

You can find an example :
[sqlites does not load .sqliterc in Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.8.13.16 armv7l)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24381617/sqlites-does-not-load-sqliterc-in-ubuntu-13-10-gnu-linux-3-8-13-16-armv7l)

Good Luck!!