# sqlites does not load .sqliterc in Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 3.8.13.16 armv7l)

Tags: sqlite

version

```
>sqlite3 --version
3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22 118a3b35693b134d56ebd780123b7fd6f1497668
```

environment

```
>uname -a
Linux odroid 3.8.13.16 #1 SMP PREEMPT ... armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

my .sqliterc file

```
.mode column
.headers on
.timer on
```

[Problem]

"sqlite3 -init ~/.sqliterc mydatabase.db" loads .sqliterc,but "sqlite3 mydatabase.db" does not load .sqliterc.

Is there any other way to set the sqlite default environment with resources file?

Please give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I found my misunderstanding of ~(home directory).

/etc/passwd

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
myname:x:0:1003::/home/myname:/bin/bash
```

I logined as myname.

odroid-root:/home/myname> whoami

```
root
```

odroid-root:/home/myname> echo $HOME

```
/home/myname
```

odroid-root:/home/myname> su

root@odroid:/home/myname# echo $HOME

```
/root
```

[SOLVE]

I put my .sqliterc to /root/, and sqlite3 loads my /root/.sqliterc.